# Error with MATLAB batch function

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use batch to simply run 5 parallel instances of a script.  As a test I tried this:

```
for ii = 1:5
  jj{ii} = batch('magic(5000)');
end
wait(jj{5});
```

This appears to work, however I get a big nasty warning at each of the 5 times through.  It's on a non-networked machine, but the headline is:

"Warning: Objects of class 'parallel.job.CJSIndependentJob' cannot be saved to MAT files."

This error is actually repeated 4 times per loop iteration.

Any ideas what the problem is here?  I'm not intending to save anything to disk.

Comment: have you checked out this question/answer, its similar to yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381574/matlab-createtask-with-parcluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning appears because *by default* when the [`batch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/batch.html) command is used to invoke a script (or a string, as here), it captures the entire workspace and sends it to the workers so that they can use it for their computations. This lets you do stuff like this:

```
x = 100;
j = batch('size(x)')
```

and have it work.

In your case, you have two options - you can specify the `'Workspace'` option to `batch`, like so:

```
j{ii} = batch('magic(1000)', 'Workspace', struct());
```

or, you could use a function:

```
j{ii} = batch(@magic, 1, {1000}); % 1 is number of outputs requested
```